# How do I call a python function in C++ using SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig, armadillo

I have a the following C++

```
class myfun{
public:
    virtual double eval(arma::vec& x){};
};

double op(myfun* f, arma::vec& x){
    return f->eval(x);
}
```

where `arma::vec` is an armadillo c++ vector for which I am using armanpy.i to translate a numpy array as an arma::vec object and vice versa.

After enabling the swig directors, and creating a SWIG interface for the above C++ code, I create a python class which redefine's the eval virtual method:

```
class f(mymodule.myfun):
    def __init__(self):
        super(f,self).__init__()
    def eval(self,x):
        print x
        return 3.14
```

In python, I first create an instance of f, which inherits myfun:

```
b = f()
```

Then, I pass this to `op`:

```
mymodule.op(b,array([3.,4.]))
```

which outputs

```
<Swig Object of type 'arma::vec *' at 0x10e6dcc30>
3.14
```

Python is not interpreting arma::vec * as a numpy array, which I thought it was doing in the armanpy.i file. Any ideas? I am not married to arma::vec and I could replace arma::vec with a numpy vector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, have a look at [armanpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/armanpy) which provides armadillo SWIG files.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using this repository at Github which makes use of armanpy and armadillo 8.500.1

https://github.com/Wolframm74/armadillo_armanpy/blob/master/README.md

Start with compiling the code by following the steps and then building upon the examples. It has examples with how to translate python's numpy arrays into armadillo arrays via SWIG.